# While doesn't recognize the content inside a string

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a while loop to check if a content inside a string called "tipoMedia" is a exact content that I want and if isn't he keeps the while loop teeling the user to type the two options ("simples" or "ponderada"). When I run the project (SharpDevelop, the solution is a console aplication), the while loop doesn't recognize that the content inside "tipoMedia" is the right, I even printed the content inside "tipoMedia" and it shows me that the content is the right one

It works if I change the check rule to a int instead of a string
Something like

```
Won't Work: while(tipoMedia != "simples" || tipoMedia != "ponderada")
Work: while(tipoMedia != 1.0f || tipoMedia != 2.0f)

//Tells the user to choose between "simples" or "ponderada", the right ones
Console.WriteLine("Escolha o tipo de media, digite 'simples' ou 'ponderada'");
//assign what the user write to the string
tipoMedia = Console.ReadLine();
//checks if the content inside the string is the right one
while(tipoMedia != "simples" || tipoMedia != "ponderada")
            {
            //Tells the user that the answer is wrong and the right options
            Console.WriteLine("A opção digitada esta incorreta, digite 'simples' ou 'ponderada'");
            tipoMedia = Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

[Console showing while loop even with the right answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqQpp.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(tipoMedia != "simples" || tipoMedia != "ponderada")
```

For this line to evaluate to false, tipoMedia has to be not simples **and** not ponderada.

tipoMedia can only be either "simples" or "ponderada", but not both. Thus your while condition will always evaluate to true.
(For example, when tipoMedia is "simples", tipoMedia != "simples" is false, but tipoMedia != "ponderada" is true, so the while condition is still true)

Change your || to && and you should get the results you are expecting.

```
while(tipoMedia != "simples" && tipoMedia != "ponderada")
```

Or, alternatively using [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
while (! (tipoMedia == "simples" || tipoMedia == "ponderada"))
```

Comment: What do you think is the best habit to build when checking this type of condition? Demorgan's Laws or using &&? I knew about the && but didn't get the "click" inside my head, thank you

Comment: @BuddyKO, DeMorgan's laws just mean that `( !x && !y )` is equivalent to `( ! (x || y) )` and vice versa. Since they are logically equivalent, either would be fine, so just pick whichever formulation that is more readable to you.